# What are ‘I Space’ and ‘D Space’ on osx and the difference between them

Tags: ios, macos, ptrace

In sys/ptrace.h, i saw something like:

```
@define PT_READ_I  1 /* read world in child's I space*/
@define PT_READ_D  2 /* read world in child's D space*/
@define PT_READ_U  3 /* read world in child's user structure*/
```

What are  ‘I Space’ and ‘D Space’ and 'user structure'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting the man page:

> Traditionally, ptrace() has
>                      allowed for machines with distinct address spaces for
>                      instruction and data, which is why there are two requests:
>                      conceptually, PT_READ_I reads from the **instruction space**
>                      and PT_READ_D reads from the **data space**.  In the current
>                      NetBSD implementation, these two requests are **completely
>                      identical.**

Now about PT_READ_U:

> This space contains the registers and  other  information  about  the
>            process; its layout corresponds to the **user structure** in the system.

Comment: If i only know the address, what should i do,you probably don't know where it is(probably in heap space),am i right?

Comment: From where did you get the address?  Usually, you should have some clue.  In any case, though, as Macmade said, it doesn't matter.